# How to insert timestampz values in postgresql table using php

Tags: php, postgresql, timezone

We have one 2 field in of type 'timestampz' like createdon & updatedon

createdon field is inserted using '`Now()`' function of postgresql.

and i need to insert updatedon field by using php.
like i try to insert using '`date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , $timestamp );`'.

When i try to get updated field is gives me wrong result.

I want to know i want to insert timestampz using php how i can to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do something like "UPDATE table SET ..., updatedon = NOW() WHERE ..."?

Comment: hey we don't want to set updatedon as NOW()...its dynamical create based on some input...

Answer (score 3):

The following article describes how to implement the *timestamp* behavior of MySql with Postgres:

- http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/05/08/mysqls-timestamp-in-postgresql/

It works by creating a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_handle_timestamp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.y = OLD.y THEN NEW.y := now(); END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER trg_handle_timestamp 
BEFORE UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_handle_timestamp();
```